# Do you replace tokens moved to the Trade Route mat?

Tags: dominion, dominion-prosperity

With Trade Route in play, do you replace the coins on the victory cards after the first card is purchased?

Example: I buy a Duchy and move the coin to the Trade Route mat.  Do I put another coin token on the remaining stack of Duchies? Or is four the maximum number of coins on the Trade Route mat?

Answer (score 10):

You do not replace the coin tokens. So with Colonies in the game, and no other extra victory cards, yes, four is the maximum number of coins on the mat. Remember that there potentially are other victory cards among the kingdom cards in the game, though, depending on what expansions you're playing with - like Gardens from the base game, and many others.

Why? Because the card doesn't say to. If you're ever having trouble with Dominion rules, just read the card carefully, and do exactly what it says in the order it says.

Answer (score 2):

You do not replace them, but four is not the maximum number of coins: the kingdom may include victory cards like Harem, Gardens, or Feodum.

Answer (score 1):

Trade Route tokens are never replaced.  They're either on the Victory cards or on the Trade Route mat.  Remember that if you gain a card, you also transfer the token over to the mat.  Last but not least, each Victory card, whether it's a starter card (e.g. Estate, Duchy, Province, Colony) or Kingdom card (e.g. Garden, Fairground, etc.) starts off with a token on it.